# What is ec2.ServiceResource() returned from ec2.instances in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

When I use the `e2.instances` method it returns a collection of `ec2.instances` per the documentation that I can iterate over.

However when I print the returned collection I see:

```
ec2.instancesCollection(ec2.ServiceResource(), ec2.Instance)...
```

What is the `ec2.ServiceResource()`?

Comment: have you looked at http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#service-resource

Comment: I have, unfortunately I don't understand what it means in the context of the collection returned.